# Can't reach my home server from outside

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu, isp

I have a static ip address granted by my ISP. I have a small home server (Ubuntu server+ Apache) and I maintain a website which used to be reachable by domain name and by ip address. Suddenly I realized I can't reach my website- instead of a page there is a pop up window asking for my DSL router username and password. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Are you attempting to access it from _inside_ or _outside_ your own LAN? (It does not matter if you're using a public address. What matters is where you are connecting from.)

Comment: If you haven't fixed this yet, I'd fix immediately. I'd turn off WAN configuration in your router, this is a major security hole.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward the port(s) to your webserver (80) to the correct IP within your LAN.

Comment: The ports are forwarded (actually the whole system worked for many months, I did not change anything, it just stopped working).

Comment: You need to make sure that management of your router from outside is turned *off*.  A recent firmware update may have changed the setting?